# htaccess mobile redirect works on one server, gives 500 error on another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I'm trying to implement the htaccess mobile browser detection script from detectmobilebrowsers.com. The format is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego) .... [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso) .... [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/mobile [R,L]
```

This script works perfectly on my own website (hosted by mediaTemple) but will not parse on my work site, hosted by XO Communiations, which apparently is very strict with htaccess rules and provides little support, as detailed [here](http://www.katemorris.com/2010/02/yes-i-hate-xo-communications.html) for example. The server will throw a "500 Internal Server Error."

Beyond the basics, I'm not too familiar with coding htaccess files, so I'm hoping someone might have some insight as to how one might implement this type of redirect script in a "strict" server environment. The blogger in the site I reference above states that "if [the htaccess file] isn’t coded and loaded as a UNIX file, there are line break issues that cause issues"-- I'm not sure if this can provide any direction here, but any assistance is greatly appreciated. For the time being, I'm using a JavaScript-based redirect, but would vastly prefer an htaccess-based approach if possible. I figured I'd try asking here before dealing with XO's lackluster support...

Comment: Does the 500 error occur regardless of whether you're using one of the mobile browsers that matches the signature? If it's occurring for any browsing of the site, period, that's different than if it's only occurring when the rule matches.

Comment: Hi David-- the 500 error occurs with any browser agent, whether on the desktop or on a matched mobile device. I'm thinking that the XO servers either don't like the rule itself or the way it's formatted in the htaccess file...